# Checking for and installing prereqs with Install Shield

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, installshield

I'm creating my first install using the Install Shield version that ships with VS 2010.

On vista and 7 only the .NET 4.0 client is required, but on XP my application reqires:

1. .NET 2.0 (I think this is required
   for the following prereqs)
2. XP Update KB968930 (Windows
   Management Framework Core)
3. XP Update KB971513 (Microsoft Active
   Accessibility Package)
4. SAPI 5.1 (Text to Speech and Speech
   Recognition)

When testing the application I've just manually run the exe for each of those (for SAPI I used the old SAPI 5.1 sdk to make sure it's installed which seems overkill). I was thinking of just creating an exe file which would run all four executables and then run the installer (or I think I could via a VB Script inside Install Shield?)

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to check for these, prompt the user for each one, and then quietly install as part of the install using Install Shield? Or just a simple way to package them into an install.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield 2010 Limited Edition uses .PRQ files but doesn't come with a PRQ editor.  You have a few options:

1) Work out the XML schema ( there's no XSD provided ) for the .PRQ files and edit it by hand and update the ISM XML by hand to reference the newly added PRQ files.

2) Spend about $1500 to upgrade to InstallShield 2010 Professional Edition.

3) Evaluate InstallShield 2010 Pro to generate the PRQ files and update the ISM by hand to reference the PRQ files ( way easier then #1 but still not for the faint of heart )

4) Engage a consultant to help you get this done. :-)

Comment: I've contemplated reverse engineering the XSD for the XML and creating my own Prereq editor but I've been too swamped to do it and I'm concerned that I'd draw too much heat for doing it.  Still, I have a framework ready to do it if I ever get around to it.